# Pandas - merge two dataframes based off of intersection of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am new to dataframe manipulation. I've been playing around with df.merge, df.join, pd.concat and I've been getting frequent errors while being unable to merge without duplicates.

I have two representative dataframes I want to merge.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'1990' : 1, '1991': 2, '1992': 3}, index = ['a','b','c'])
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1989':0,'1990' : 1, '1991': 2, '1992': 3, '1993': 4}, index = ['d'])
```

[image]

I want to merge them by the intersection of the columns of the two dataframes while adding the row at the same time. Is there a way to use a dataframe method to do this?

The final product should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `inner` join:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')
print (df)
   1990  1991  1992
a     1     2     3
b     1     2     3
c     1     2     3
d     1     2     3
```

Comment: I did exactly that earlier and received a ValueError. But your comment made me realize it wasn't the pd.concat I did improperly. Rather, one of the dataframes has repeated column keys causing problems with the concatenation. Thank you! Saved me another hour of trying to understand why I was struggling with merging things....

Comment: @Will - So is possible remove duplicated columns names? Like `df1=df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.duplicated()]` ?

Comment: For my situation I can't remove duplicated columns - I'm just using a groupby to process them now. Thanks again!